# Magento 2 product Categories not loading

Tags: category, product-attribute, magento-2.1.7

I have this but and I'm not sure if anyone else has it Magento 2.1.7.

Sometimes when adding or editing a product the Categories info isn't being loaded into the field.

Any help would be great thanks

[image]

Comment: See in developer console what error you are getting and post it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by fixing the parent category for my categories.
I found in the database the parent category of my category is the same category itself. 
see image bellow the category with the id (2) was linked to parent_id = 2 so I just return the parent_id to (1) and then reindex and clear_cache
and every things went good.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had a similar issue in my Magento 2.4.3 CE and solved using your method. Actually I had created a sub-category name exactly as the main category name and things got messed up.

i.e. main category 'entity_id' pointing to sub-category 'parent_id' and sub-category 'entity_id' pointing to 'main category 'parent_id'

If anyone have similar issues, check the table 'catalog_category_entity' first

*select entity_id, parent_id from catalog_category_entity;*