# Undefined index: optgroup in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/Component/Product/Form/Categories/Options.php on line 103

Tags: product, category, backend

Categories do not load when I am editing a product, I can't even select them.
The customer changed the url of the category and then this error occurred.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Try doing a reindex from CLI. I've seen this happen in Magento 1, but it was a 3rd party module causing the categories to mess up. Might be worth disabling any modules you've added if you havent already tried that.

Comment: Thank you, but still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, my version is 2.4.2 and I still haven't found a suitable solution.

Answer (score 2):

First! confirm your store is in an local envrionment,
Use below SQL to Reset Database Category data;

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_int;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_text;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index;

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, 
`parent_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `path`, `position`, `level`, 
`children_count`) VALUES ('1', '0', '0', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1', '0', '0', '1'),
('2', '3', '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '1/2', '1', '1', 
'0');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_int` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, 
`store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '69', '0', '1', '1'),
('2', '46', '0', '2', '1'),
('3', '69', '0', '2', '1');

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar` (`value_id`, `attribute_id`, 
`store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES 
('1', '45', '0', '1', 'Root Catalog'),
('2', '45', '0', '2', 'Default Category');

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: I have a lot of categories and I don't want to reset the categories, I just want to know what is the reason for this happening? And how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could help in solving the issue without reseting the categories.

[Magento 2 product Categories not loading](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191296/magento-2-product-categories-not-loading/350794#350794)